# varchar '09/16/2016 17:28:25 IST' to datetime in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, type-conversion, varchar, str-to-date

I need to convert '09/16/2016 17:28:25 IST' to datetime in mysql. I tried many options but it is returning null.

Tried Options:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('09/16/2016 17:28:25 IST', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
select CAST(LEFT('09/16/2016 17:28:25 IST',19) as date)
```

Comment: Hint:  `str_to_date()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
STR_TO_DATE('09/16/2016 17:28:25 IST','%c/%e/%Y %H:%i')
```